# Is it possible to install latest version of RaySession on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, mate, session, qt5, usability

I'm testing RaySession [application](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=raysession).

I have started with its version from official repository. But it seems to be outdated.

So I decided to get latest master from GitHub project page https://github.com/Houston4444/RaySession by the commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/Houston4444/RaySession.git
cd RaySession
```

Then I follow official [INSTALL.md file](https://github.com/Houston4444/RaySession/blob/master/INSTALL.md):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 pyqt5-dev-tools qtchooser
make
```

and I get

> ```
> pyuic5 resources/ui/proxy_gui.ui -o src/clients/proxy/ui_proxy_gui.py
> lrelease locale/raysession_en.ts -qm locale/raysession_en.qm
> lrelease: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/lrelease': No such file or directory
> make: *** [Makefile:93: locale/raysession_en.qm] Error 1
> ```

How should I proceed to avoid the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lrelease` executable is contained in two [development packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=lrelease). We have already installed one of them - `qtchooser`, so we also need to install the second one - `qttools5-dev-tools` which provides `/usr/lib/qt5/bin/lrelease` file:

```
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

and then resume compilation by

```
cd ~/Downloads/RaySession
make
sudo make install
```

Then we need to install two additional packages to resolve runtime dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install liblo7 python3-liblo wmctrl
```

and finally enjoy the RaySession application.